# check how close an object is to another .js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an array of HTML elements and I need to check if one of the elements is close enough to each of the other elements in the array.

The `top` and `left` of `character` and `enemies[i]` should be between `0px` to `5px` apart for the if to be `true`:

```js
function killenemy() {      
  for(let i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
     if((character.style.top == enemies[i].style.top) && (character.style.left == enemies[i].style.left)){
       console.log('enemy is closer than 5px');
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to check the distance between 2 objects is by using the `getBoundingClientRect()` property. First you would define this for both of your objects:

```js
let c_offsets = character.getBoundingClientRect();
let e_offsets = enemy.getBoundingclientRect();
```

Then you can get the `top` and `left` value of both the character and the enemy.

```js
let c_top = c_offsets.top;
let c_left = c_offsets.left;

let e_top = e_offsets.top;
let e_left = e_offsets.left;
```

After that, you can just apply the mathematical distance formula:

[image: Distance]

In `JavaScript`, you could use the following function:

```js
function point(x1, y1, x2, y2){
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x1 - x2), 2) + Math.pow((y1 - y2), 2));
}
```

After that, just call the function with your values:

```js
let distance = point(c_left, c_top, e_left, e_top);
```

That should do it!